# Rhythmbox: Cannot edit properties

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox, music

Could you help me out with a noob problem?

I used to be able to edit song properties in Rhythmbox (14.04) via generic user GUI stuff. Right click, hit edit properties, type what you need to, right? Approximately two months ago, whenever I hit 'Properties' on one of my songs to edit its properties, it won't let me delete the 'Unknown' placeholder so I can organize my music.

This has been a long-term issue that didn't occur in the past. This is getting to be quite annoying, and I would love it if someone would help me fix this. A list of commands or a package download would be helpful. Thank you.

Edit:
Alright, I opened it from a terminal. I still cannot edit song properties. It's still glitchy. However, here's the feedback I got when I opened it from terminal.

`r----e@r-----e:~$ rhythmbox`

`(rhythmbox:31606): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_css_provider_load_from_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed`

`(rhythmbox:31606): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: object SoupServer 0x872a148 finalized while still in-construction`

`(rhythmbox:31606): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Custom constructor for class SoupServer returned NULL (which is invalid). Please use GInitable instead.`
`Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.`

What does this mean? I'm still looking for help here.

Comment: So is the properties menu option available when you right-click - is it greyed out?  What happens when you click the properties menu option?  If you start rhythmbox from a terminal and then choose properties - does any error messages appear in a terminal?  What type of music file are you trying to edit - e.g. mp3? mp4?

Comment: No, The properties box is still there. I just can't delete or type anything when I open it. I don't know what command to use to open it from a terminal. It's a .wav file, but the problem exists with all the other file types I've tried.

Comment: just type rhythmbox from a terminal

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a permissions problem. Try this:

```
chmod u+w /path/to/music/folder -R
```

If that's not the case, note that editing properties un *.wma files is not supported